# Xamarin NetworkReachability SetCallBack method issue after migrating to x64 iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

After migrating my iOS project to x64 I got lots of errors and I fixed all just I can't fix the following one , I searched a lot on both Xamarin and Apple developer sites but not solved.

```
Error CS1061: Type `SystemConfiguration.NetworkReachability' does not contain a definition for `SetCallback' and no extension method `SetCallback' of type `SystemConfiguration.NetworkReachability' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061)
```

Also I imported the following references :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using SystemConfiguration;
using CoreFoundation;
using CoreServices;
```

And the code is :

```
NetworkReachability reachability = new NetworkReachability (new IPAddress (new byte [] {169,254,0,0}));
reachability.SetCallback (OnChange); // <-- seems that this method removed from the class But what I should use instead of it ?
```

Please share your suggestions with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to use `reachability.SetNotification()` instead.

`SetCallback()` is not recommended anymore:

```
[Advice ("Use SetNotification instead")]
public bool SetCallback (NetworkReachability.Notification callback)
{
    return this.SetNotification (callback) == StatusCode.OK;
}
```

Comment: This method has the same functionality ?

Comment: where do you get all this information? the api reference on the xamarin site is lacking when it comes to systemconfiguration (both monotouch and monomac)

Comment: @krumelur reachability.SetNotification() i have used in my code but it is showing error "no overload for method setNotification takes 0 arguments"

Comment: I guess change Setcallback to SetNotification simply is not enough everytime, because at in this demo http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/870548/Xamarin-forms-Check-network-connectivity-in-iOS-an it's use Setcallback but changing to SetNotification, it's don't work.